# How do I tell Selenium that an Angular controller has "loaded"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium

I've got some UI tests that are attempting to test that a click on an element makes something else appear.  There's an existing check for all tests that looks to see if the DOM is Ready, however there's a small amount of time between that even firing and the app.controller() calls all completing where my test could jump in and wrongly determine that the click handler has not been added.

I can use angular.element('[ng-controller=myController]').scope() to determine if the scope is defined, however there is still a very small window where the test could run before the click handler is bound (a very, very small window).

`<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-click="doWork()"></div>
</div>`

Can anyone see a way to tell that the click handler has been added?

PS: There's an event that fires within a controller when the controller has loaded:`$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){  });` But that doesn't really help me unless I subscribe to it in the controller and flag a variable somewhere that I can check via Selenium.

PPS: A lot of these have classes that change when scope changes and they can be used to trigger the test, but many do not.

Comment: I think you will have a bad time trying to do this in Selenium. Its just not meant for testing Angular applications. You can probably figure it out, but my advise would be to use Protractor instead - https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/

Comment: There's a decent amount of institutional momentum behind Selenium at this point. That probably isn't politically feasible :)

Comment: I'm confused... Doesn't protractor use Selenium?

Comment: Protractor is basically a wrapper around selenium javascript webdriver.

Comment: Mostly the hang up is that it uses its own test execution framework. We're heavily invested in running selenium via xUnit at the moment and switching the tests to Jasmine would be a decent amount of overhead.

Comment: Since we're all so keen on Protractor, I took a look at the code on github
It makes heavy use of `getTestability`, I'm researching if I can use some of the functionality exposed by Protractor in vanilla Selenium.

Comment: @TheHonorableSamuelClemens could you share the reasons why you have unaccepted the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe: I accidentally accepted it. The unaccept was fixing that

Comment: Protractor will run with any framework, including custom frameworks. I'm running it with Cucumber and Chai at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

There is a specialized tool for testing AngularJS application - [`protractor`](https://github.com/angular/protractor). It is basically a wrapper around WebDriverJS - selenium javascript webdriver.

The main benefit of using `protractor` is that it *knows when Angular is settled down and ready*. It makes your tests flow in a natural way without having to use Explicit Waits:

> You no longer need to add waits and sleeps to your test. Protractor
>   can automatically execute the next step in your test the moment the
>   webpage finishes pending tasks, so you don’t have to worry about
>   waiting for your test and webpage to sync.

It also provides several unique AngularJS-specific locators, like `by.model`, `by.binding` etc. And, in general, it provides a very [convenient and well-designed API](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api) for end-to-end testing.

Comment: I really need something in boring old Selenium sans Protractor (but thank you for your response)

Comment: @TheHonorableSamuelClemens but you would still have the ability to use selenium webdriver directly via `browser.driver`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues to overcome here:

- How do we know when Angular is done (with the sub issue of "what does done mean?"
- How do we get that information to Selenium

Angular provides a method called "getTestability" that can be called with any element (assuming you've included it, it is optional). Usage:
`angular.getTestability(angular.element('body')).whenStable(function(){/*Do things*/})`
That seems to solve the first problem...
But, now what does Done mean in this case. Done means that anything that uses $browser.defer will have been executed. What does that mean? No idea, but in practice it at least verifies that there are no http requests in play when the callback is called.

Ok, now Selenium... You can ask it to execute JavaScript on the client and use the code above to set a variable. `.whenStable(function(){window.someVar=true})` and then poll in the test until that variable is set.

Will this catch all cases of "Done"? Probably not, but it made my tests pass more consistently. As long as it works I'm not going to think any harder on the issue.

That said, I'm not marking this as the answer. It feels like a dirty solution.

Comment: You might also be able to access a controller's scope and set $on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){  }); to achieve the same results.